# Run Python 2.7 sript from C# with command line params

Tags: c#, python-2.7, process

How do I run this python 2.7 code from C# (file name is `myPythonScript.py`):

```
import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        '-sd', '-start_date', help='start date to download data')
    parser.add_argument(
        '-ed', '-end_date', help='end date to download data')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    #print(args.accumulate(args.start_date))    
    print(args.sd, args.ed)
```

Above code only takes two dates as command line params and shows it to the user. I want to run it as a process from C#.
When I use this C# code it runs script without params well. But when I add params it can`t find python file. Why? How to resolve this?

```
       ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Anaconda2\python.exe";
            // path to my python script 
            string appEXE = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            // this scripts runs without params
            python_script_name = @"myPythonScript.py -sd 01/01/2015 -ed 05/09/2017";
            startInfo.Arguments="\""+appEXE+ "Python\\"+ python_script_name + "\"";
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            using (Process process = Process.Start(startInfo))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
                {
                    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    //MessageBox.Show("Normal results"+result);
                    Debug.WriteLine(result);
                }
                process.WaitForExit();
                // This will show error: no such file or directory
                MessageBox.Show("Errors"+process.StandardError.ReadToEnd());
                GC.Collect();
```

Comment: For starters, try using `System.IO.Path.Combine()` any time you concatenate paths together. So maybe you would use `Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Python", "myPythonScript.py")` I don't know if thats the problem, but it may help make it more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these lines out:

```
        string scriptPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Python", "myPythonScript.py")

        startInfo.Arguments = "\"" + scriptPath + "\"" + " -sd 01/01/2015 -ed 05/09/2017"
```

I think you had an issue with quotation marks.